# Figure size 1440x720 with 0 Axes - how to plot bigger figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, arima

I'd like to plot bigger figure. As recommended in previous post I started with
<fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))> - nothing changed

Could you advise where I am wrong..[image: this my first unsuccessful try]
[image: This is second option - doesn't work]

Comment: Please note that screenshots of code are not permitted here, instead [edit] your question with the code as text. See [reprex] and [ask], thanks.

Comment: @BigBen your advise is GRANTED! I'll write as the instructions. Thanks!

Comment: 2 years are passed, we're still waiting it for XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't supply an existing `Axes` object using the `ax=` kwarg when you use `df.plot`, `pandas` will create a new figure, and plot on there, which is why it is ignoring your larger existing figure.

So, you could create and `Axes` object and pass that in when you use `df.plot`.

Instead of `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))`, try using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))

...

df.plot(x='date', y='GVA', legend=True, color='g', ax=ax)

...
```

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted - it didn't resolve the plot but I will continue reading as the first suggestion and will try variation of your advise as well.